# Why a Java 6 JDK is required, even if I wish to use a Java 7 JDK while installing JBOSS EAP 6?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Please look at the URL https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/pdf/Installation_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-6.2-Installation_Guide-en-US.pdf

**Refer Chapter 3. System Requirements**
**3.1. JBoss EAP 6 Installation Prerequisites**

A Java 6 JDK is required. This can be obtained by subscribing to the supplementary software
channel for your Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation. For example; the channel for Red Hat
Enterprise Linux version 6 installed on i386 architecture is rhel-i386-server-supplementary-
6.

**Important**
**A Java 6 JDK is required, even if you wish to use a Java 7 JDK**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can remember that I tried to use the Sun JDK 7 for JBoss and some libraries just would not work with Java 7 - in particular an XML processing library. There are certainly other things that don't work that I didn't encounter. On the Internet one finds various [indications about problems](http://vyazelenko.com/2012/02/01/is-your-project-ready-for-java-7/), so you are sure to encounter problems in such a large software as JBoss which additionally uses invasive software composition at many places.

On the other hand, I see that JBoss 6.3 is ok with JDK 1.6 and 1.7: [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP) 6 Supported Configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663). That page is reached from [JBoss EAP 6 Installation Prerequisites](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Getting_Started_Guide/chap-Prerequisites.html#JBoss_EAP_6_Installation_Prerequisites). So why not go with 6.3?